# Down hosts are shown up when scanned all 256 hosts in aggregate

Tags: nmap

When I used

nmap -sP IP/24 -v,

nmap scanned for around 5 minutes. Then it reported that all 256 hosts are up.

But when I used

nmap -sP * .* .*.253 -v

it said the host wasn't up.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nmap -sO -v IP/24.
-sO means IP protocol scan. 
You can also see which machines are open in this scan.